# Follow foreign key in function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, foreign-keys

I have been trying to find this online but I'm new to postgresql and I probably don't know enough to quickly filter out search results..

I have declared the following tables:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE country_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE country
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('country_id_seq'),
  name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT country_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE user
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'),
  first_name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  last_name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  country_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT user_fk_country_id FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
      REFERENCES country (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

Now I want to create a trigger function on `USER` that (for example purposes) raises an exception with country name

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_user_deny() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'STUFF %', NEW.country_id.name;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_user_deny_insert
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON customer
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_user_deny();
```

So basically my question is: how do I do something like `NEW.country_id.name` (which doesn't work and the purpose is to `select country.name from country where id=NEW.country_id`)?

Comment: What is for you NEW.country_id.name? It does not exist on the table. If you intend to have country name from country table, you have to query that table.

Comment: What do you mean, it does not exist on the table? country_id is an FK to country table and country table has name.. I assumed the purpose of the statement was clear with the table schemas but I could have elaborated, you're right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but I think you want the name of the country which has `id = "user".country_id`.
In this case you have to query the table `country` with the new value in the table `user`:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION trigger_user_deny() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'STUFF %', name from country WHERE id = NEW.country_id;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

PS: if you name a table `user`, which is PostgreSQL keyword, you must always double quote it in queries and other sql statements:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" ....
```

Comment: I hoped plpgsql would be able to follow up FKs "ORM style" :) Thanks for the tip on reserved keywords and also on the syntax without "SELECT"; I was using SELECT name FROM country WHERE ... INTO myVar; and then using myVar :)